# Python selenium with date-picker

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

I'm trying to automate something with the datepicker, some of the sites let you enter a date instead of browsing for it, run into an issue where Expedia does not work with send_key(date).
Can somebody help me with this?
stuck for a few hours now.
My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#travel dates
first_date = '08/29/2021'
last_date = '09/03/2021'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = 'https://expedia.com'
driver.get(url)
start_date = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#d1-btn")))
end_date = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#d2-btn")))
start_date.click()
# This is what i used to do with date-picker
start_date.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a')
start_date.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
start_date.send_keys(first_date)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: no getting any errors, just can not select any dates by send_key, looks like I have to click the arrow > to get to the date, then click

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to use the send_keys since the calendar doesnt allow a keyboard input to filter/focus the searched date. Instead you could use the fact that the dates have the aria-label attributes, with the exact date, and then click on it.

Below i've create some functions that do just that. The downside is that the input dates should be in this format 'Sep 12, 2021' ('%b %d, %Y'). You can tinker with the datetime format, ofcourse, to use the dates like this '08/29/2021'

1. Initially search if the date is on the calendar view
2. If the date is not, then click on the right arrow key until its available for click

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import datetime

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/drivers/chromedriver.exe")

driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = 'https://expedia.com'
driver.get('https://expedia.com')

driver.get(url)
start_date = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#d1-btn")))
end_date = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#d2-btn")))
start_date.click()

# convert the date from 'Aug 12, 2021' to 'August 2021'


def date_formater(date):
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d, %Y')
    return d.strftime('%B %Y')

# create a function to right click until the date is found in the calendar


def press_right_arrow_until_date_is_found(date):
    # get the text of the initial calendar
    current_calendar = driver.find_element_by_class_name("uitk-calendar").text
    # while the date does not appear in the calendar view press right arrow until it does
    while(date_formater(date) not in current_calendar):
        right_arrow = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            "//button[@data-stid='date-picker-paging']")[1]
        right_arrow.click()
        current_calendar = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
            "uitk-calendar").text

# function to select the dates using xpath with the unique attribute. Ex: aria-label="Aug 12, 2021"


def select_date(start_date_calendar, end_date_calendar):
    # press right until the start date is found
    press_right_arrow_until_date_is_found(start_date_calendar)
    # click on the date that matches the xpath with the aria-label
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//button[@aria-label='{}']".format(start_date_calendar)).click()

    # press right until the end date is found
    press_right_arrow_until_date_is_found(end_date_calendar)
    # click on the date that matches the xpath with the aria-label
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//button[@aria-label='{}']".format(end_date_calendar)).click()


select_date('Sep 12, 2021', 'Dec 9, 2021')
```